# Can Ancillary library be used for sharing accepted connections between unrelated processes (not forked ones)?

Tags: c++, c, linux, connection, interprocess

We create app A. start it from super user. It opens socket and waits for connections. Connection establishes. We want to let another, not forked, separately launched by super user process to take that established connection and be capable to send data over it not interrupting/reestablishing it. We create both A and B apps and we can implement any required logical algorithms into them both. How shall our apps logic look like? and will Ancillary library be capable to help me with such task?

Answer (score 4):

You can open a unix domain socket between the processes and pass file descriptors over it. See this site for an explanation and example:

http://www.lst.de/~okir/blackhats/node121.html